# Recode program without using String[] split?

Tags: java, arrays

```
//Split string starts on the while loop
```

I am trying to recode this program without using a String [] split method. Is there a way that I can get around this?

Like a different method of some sort? or am I stuck with using the method?

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.File;

    public class Assignment3 {


      public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        //create format for date
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a");
        //output date 
        System.out.println("Welcome to the batch grade calculator");
        System.out.println("Start time is: " +sdf.format(new Date()));
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

        Assignment3 calc = new Assignment3();
        //calculate grade for students
        calc.calculateGrade();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Current end time : " +sdf.format(new Date()));

      }


      public void calculateGrade() throws IOException {

        System.out.print("Input grade file: ");
        //read data form file, entered by user
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(input.next()));
        //declare variables
        String id="";
        String Lname="";
        String Fname="";
        int q[]=  new int[5];
        int a[] = new int[4];
        int mt=0;
        int fe=0;
        int pr=0;

        int QUIZZES=5;
        int ASSIGNMENTS=4;

        int processed=0;
        int failed=0;
        double sumOfgrades=0;

        // create file  entered by user
        System.out.print("Otput grade file: ");
        Scanner output = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File (output.next());
        // use writer to read information from file
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter (file);
        //print header of file
        printWriter.printf("%5s", "Grade");
        printWriter.printf("%10s", "ID");
        printWriter.printf("%20s", "Quizzess");
        printWriter.printf("%20s", "Assignments");
        printWriter.printf("%20s", "Midterm");
        printWriter.printf("%20s", "Final");
        printWriter.printf("%20s", "Professionalism");
        printWriter.println();

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
          printWriter.print("===================");
        }

        printWriter.println();

        //read header of file
        if(scanner.hasNext())
          scanner.nextLine();

        //use loop to read each line 
        **while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
        {   
          // read line
          String  line=scanner.nextLine();
          //split line
          // ***the split method starts on this line.
          String[] split=line.split("\t");

          int k=0;
          //get id, last name, first name
          id=split[k++];
          Lname=split[k++];
          Fname=split[k++];


          double sum=0;
          //get quizzes
          for(int i=0;i<QUIZZES;i++)
          {
            q[i]= Integer.parseInt(split[k++]);
            sum+=q[i];
          }

          // evaluate average quiz mark
          double quizMark=sum/QUIZZES;


          sum=0;
          // get assignments
          for(int i=0;i<ASSIGNMENTS;i++)
          {
            a[i]=Integer.parseInt(split[k++]);
            sum+=a[i];
          }
          // evaluate average assignment mark
          double assignmentsMark =sum/ASSIGNMENTS;


          mt=Integer.parseInt(split[k++]);
          fe=Integer.parseInt(split[k++]);
          pr=Integer.parseInt(split[k++]);****

          double TECHNICAL_MARK=calculateTechnicalMark(quizMark,assignmentsMark,mt,fe);
          double grade=  (TECHNICAL_MARK * 4 +pr)/5.0;

          // print information about each student
          String s="";
          if(grade <50)
            s+="*";
          printWriter.printf("%5s", s+ "["+ getLetterGrade(grade)+"]");
          printWriter.printf("%10s", id);
          printWriter.printf("%20s", getLetterGrade(quizMark));
          printWriter.printf("%20s", getLetterGrade(assignmentsMark));
          printWriter.printf("%20s", getLetterGrade(mt));
          printWriter.printf("%20s", getLetterGrade(fe));
          printWriter.printf("%20s", getLetterGrade(pr));
          printWriter.print( "\r\n");

          sumOfgrades+=grade;

          processed++;
          if(!countProfessionalism(TECHNICAL_MARK))
          {
            failed++;
          }

        }
         printWriter.print("\n\nThe * at the beginning of the line indicates that the student did not pass the course’s technical components.");

        // print main information
        System.out.println ("# students processed: "+processed);
        System.out.println ("# students who failed: "+failed);
        System.out.print ("# class average(%): ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f",sumOfgrades/processed);
        System.out.println("%");
        System.out.println("# class average(letter): "+getLetterGrade(sumOfgrades/processed));


        // close the writer
        printWriter.close (); 

        // close the scanner  
        scanner.close();

      }

      /**
       * This function will return the Letter Grade as a String for the mark passed
       * to the method as the parameter double mark
       */
      public String getLetterGrade(double mark) {

        if(mark >=90) 
          return "A+";
        else
          if(mark >=85)
          return "A";
        else
          if(mark >=80)
          return "A-";
        else
          if(mark>=77)
          return "B+";
        else
          if(mark>=73)
          return "B";
        else
          if(mark>=70)
          return "B-";
        else
          if(mark>=67)
          return"C+";
        else
          if(mark>=63)
          return "C";
        else
          if(mark>=60)
          return "C-";
        else
          if(mark>=55)
          return "D+";
        else if(mark>=50)
          return "D";
        else
          return "F";   

      }

      /**
       * This function will return the technical mark for a student given 
       * the four components that comprise the technical mark
       */
      public double calculateTechnicalMark(double quizMark, double assignmentsMark, double midtermMark, double finalMark) {
        // write function / method code her
        return (quizMark +assignmentsMark +midtermMark +finalMark )/4.0;
      }

      /**
       * This function will return true if the student can have their 
       * professional mark count towards their final mark, false otherwise 
       */
      public boolean countProfessionalism(double technicalMark) {

        if(technicalMark >50)
          return true;
        else return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: From a cursory glance, it looks like you are simply splitting an input line of text and extracting information from it, with the help of `String.split()`.  There is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: You've posted over 200 lines of code, most of which is likely to be irrelevant to the problem - and your only description of the problem seems to be that you don't want to use `String.split`, for no clear reason. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You can use `StringTokenizer` or you have to implement the split by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can simply use ***Scanner*** or ***OpenCSV***

**Sample file: sample.txt**

```
row1col1    row1col2    row1col3
row2col1    row2col2    row2col3
row3col1    row3col2    row3col3
```

#### Here is a simple example with OpenCSV:

```
final String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/sample.txt";
try (final CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath), '\t')) {
  String [] nextLine;
  while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
      System.out.println(nextLine[0] + " - " + nextLine[1] + " - " + nextLine[2]);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
row1col1 - row1col2 - row1col3
row2col1 - row2col2 - row2col3
row3col1 - row3col2 - row3col3
```

OpenCSV is available in Maven, here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/2.3

#### Here is a simple example with Scanner:

```
final String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/sample.txt";
try (final Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(filePath))) {
  while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(sc.next());
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
row1col1
row1col2
row1col3
row2col1
row2col2
row2col3
row3col1
row3col2
row3col3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're exploring the alternatives from performance standpoint, below is a comparison of 4 methods from Java SE:

1. String.split
2. StringTokenizer
3. Pattern.split()
4. Scanner

Test program and comparison results are [here](https://gist.github.com/sachinlala/0c5b3a9cc61e20d4a78723a671346989).

While the StringTokenizer performs best amongst the 4 methods I compared, a word of caution from the javadoc:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

The String.split() method is simplest to use but Pattern.split() is more performant at the cost of an additional step.